# Netbeans 6.9 uses 50-60% CPU

Tags: netbeans

Netbeans eats 50-60% CPU all the time and I installed NB for PHP only and Yii framework.

My PC detail: Intel(R) Pentium(R) Dual CPU E2200 @2.20GHz(2CPU), 1526MB Ram.

Should I upgrade my PC or have right way to solve out this problem?

Comment: even eclipse hogs too much of memory!

Comment: Only 50-60%? Luxury!

Comment: Your last question about this was migrated to superuser http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3312082/netbeans-6-9-uses-50-60-cpu-all-the-time-closed

Comment: @Mike B: I have not solved out the problem since last Q.

Comment: Reposting a question simply because the last one was not answered to your satisfaction is usually frowned upon. Not to mention reposting a question that was moved elsewhere.

Answer (score 1):

Netbeans does scan files in it's project folder when it starts, This can take some time, but after that it should no longer utilise that much CPU.

What OS and JVM you're using?

Comment: Thank you for your response.

I am using Microsoft Windows XP Professional (5.1, build 2600) 
and latest JDK at http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html

Answer (score 0):

I used Netbeans too, in my laptop (i5 with 4 Gb). Average memory usage: 1.7 Gb (!) for any project of any size. This was completely unacceptable, but I could live with it: I had more than 2Gb free for other things... (using Win 7 Pro x64).

But what really bothered me was the CPU usage (javaw: 60-70%), because the laptop got *very* hot!!

Then, I switched to eclipse. Same thing (or a little worse with CPU usage). Then I upgraded my JVM (1.6.0.xx, the last I tested: 1.0.6.0.21) with the same results. Of course, I checked for no other JVM's installed, etc. etc. I noted that the CPU usage gets high whenever netbeans or eclipse were in focus. If they were minimized or out of focus, CPU usage went down to 10-20%.

Finally I gave up and bought phpEd from nuSphere. I did prefer to spend almost $300 bucks on this software than to fry my laptop's CPU.

I don't think you have to upgrade your PC. You should better upgrade your editor, IMO.

I usually run jDownloader, a great download manager written in Java and I've never had these problems with it.

BTW, my video card is nVidia with the latest drivers available from dell. What's yours?

Answer (score 0):

Defiantly something odd going on, i'm running a old slow pentium 4 with 1.5 GB of ram and don't have a problem. Try disabling 'scan for external changes' in your setting.

By default every time you change application netbeans will scan if any file in your project has changed.

I cleared out all the extra language files that comes with yii, might be worth doing and just leaving them on your production server

If your still having problems then you could just not include the yii framework directory all together

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same issue, netbeans was sometimes using about 80% of my i7 and later on noticed my anti virus was scanning my netbeans files.. I disabled added a directory exception on my anti-virus and wolah, back down to 0.

It's since been posted on the wiki:
http://wiki.netbeans.org/FaqDisablingModules

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue, and somewhere I read it was related to CVS version control. I'm currently not using CVS but GIT.

I disabled both the CVS and the NBGIT modules (via tools > plugins > installed) and it's gone! I can seen (with Sysinternals' Process Monitor) that NB hogs the CPU *only* while it's doning an initial scan in the project's directories the Ruby directories (I use it for Rails dev.) That usually takes less than 2 minutes.

I don't know yet how to fix the NBGIT issue, but for now I'm sticking with git from CLI.

Don't know if this is your case, but hope it helps!

JLBenc